# How to remount the data after the textbox has been emptied -- REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to react. I have a component here that will automatically load the data from a database (mongo) via express server url when the page was loaded.

```
 componentDidMount() {
   var self = this;
    fetch('/movies')
    .then((resp) => resp.json())
    .then(movies => self.setState({
        movies: movies
      }))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}
```

this will load all data and display them on screen and when the user types in to the textbox it will update the display to the search term:

```
movieSearch(term){
  var self = this;

  axios.get('/moviesbytitle', {
    params: {
      term: term
    }
  })
  .then(movies => self.setState({
    movies: movies.data
  }))
  .then(() => console.log('this is is a state >>>>+++', self.state))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}

  render(){
  const movieSearch = _.debounce((term) => { this.movieSearch(term) }, 300);

  return (
    <div>
      <MovieTopBar />
      <SearchBar onSearchTermChange={movieSearch}/>
      <MovieList  movies={ this.state.movies }/>
      <MovieFooter />
    </div>
  );
}
};

class SearchBar extends Component{
 constructor(props){
   super(props);

   this.state = { term: '' };
   this.onInputChange = this.onInputChange.bind(this);
 }

 <input type="text" value={this.state.term} onChange={event => this.onInputChange(event.target.value)} className="form-control" id="" placeholder="Enter the title of the movie..." />

 onInputChange(term){
    this.setState({ term });
    this.props.onSearchTermChange(term);
  }
}
```

I am trying to find a way how can I update the data searched -> to the data when it was first mounted w/c displays the whole data whenever the textbox for search is emptied. Is there  a specific lifecycle method to do that? or do I need to do a separate function? Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @AlexGvozden said, you should move your `movieSearch` to be part of the component class, so

```
class ShowMoviesList {
    constructor() {
        this.movieSearch = this.movieSearch.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getAllMovies();
    }

    getAllMovies() {
        fetch('/movies')
        .then((resp) => resp.json())
        .then(movies => this.setState({
            movies: movies
        }))
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    }

    getMovieByTitle(term) {
        axios.get('/moviesbytitle', {
            params: {
                term: term
            }
        })
        .then(movies => this.setState({
            movies: movies.data
        }))
        .then(() => console.log('this is is a state >>>>+++', this.state))
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    }

    movieSearch(term) {
        // remember prevents blank spaces
        const currentTerm = term ? term.trim() : term;

        // remember clear last getMovieByTitle call
        if (this.timer) {
            clearTimeout(this.timer);
        }

        // if term is empty, so call getAllMovies again
        // prevent call cache movies, because cache movie will always return the first call
        // but won't render new movies if exists
        if (!currentTerm) {
            return this.getAllMovies();
        }

        this.timer = setTimeout(() => { this.getMovieByTitle(currentTerm); }, 300);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <MovieTopBar />
            <SearchBar onSearchTermChange={this.movieSearch}/>
            <MovieList  movies={ this.state.movies }/>
            <MovieFooter />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

if better call `getAllMovies`function again when `term`is empty, because you will show the real current movies instead a cache movies version from first call.

I hope it can help you.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest

```
this.movieSearch = _.debounce((term) => { this.movieSearch(term) }, 300);
```

move it to constructor

so you can avoid creating a new function each render, this will be expensive on memory

you also do not need var self = this;
using anonymous functions like `() => {}` will preserve `this`

and coming back to question, if I understood it, you want to show original movie list when user deletes input in search,

```
componentDidMount() {
   var self = this;
   fetch('/movies')
    .then((resp) => resp.json())
    .then(movies => {
      self.setState({ movies: movies });
      this.originalResults = movies;

    })).catch((err) => console.log(err));
}
```

you can do it by keeping reference to original results
and then you can add

`movieSearch(term){
   if (term === '') {
     this.setState({movies:this.originalResults})
     return; // exit the search function
   } ...rest of function`